# Ruby - Filtering array of hashes based on another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to filter an array of hashes based on another array. What's the best way to accomplish this? Here are the 2 brutes I've right now:

```
x=[1,2,3]
y = [{dis:4,as:"hi"},{dis:2,as:"li"}]

1) aa = []
x.each do |a|
  qq = y.select{|k,v| k[:dis]==a}
  aa+=qq unless qq.empty?
end

2) q = []
y.each do |k,v|
  x.each do |ele|
    if k[:dis]==ele
      q << {dis: ele,as: k[:as]}
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the output I'm intending:

`[{dis:2,as:"li"}]`

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: @MarkThomas updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to select only the elements where the value of `:dis` is included in `x`:

```
y.select{|h| x.include? h[:dis]}
```

Comment: Simple and concise, thanks! I didn't know about `include?`

Comment: Just one more question - Is it a bad idea to use `select!`, would storing it off and re-using be preferable? I don't need `y` anywhere else.

Comment: The only possible improvement I can think of is to substitute the word "included" for "contained", so it reads "...select...included...".

Comment: Haha @CarySwoveland I thought the same thing, just didn't get around to updating it. Nice to meet a fellow pedant! (Now if we can just get the Ruby maintainers to make those methods plural...)

Comment: @linuxNoob Using select! is fine if you want to change it in place (or use `keep_if` which usually reads better to me).

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the nonconforming elements of `y` in place with  with [.keep_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-keep_if)

```
> y.keep_if { |h| x.include? h[:dis] }
```

Or reverse the logic with [.delete_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
> y.delete_if { |h| !x.include? h[:dis] }
```

All produce:

```
> y
=> [{:dis=>2, :as=>"li"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes use `select`, nonetheless here's another way which works:

```
y.each_with_object([]) { |hash,obj| obj << hash if x.include? hash[:dis] }
```